# Block access by User Agent

Tags: nginx

**Goal:**

Allow access to clients whose User Agent is empty string or 'ELB-HealthChecker.*', the rest should be blocked.

I tried this code and it worked with nginx/1.2, but after the upgrade to nginx/1.2.3, it blocks everything:

```
if ($http_user_agent !~* ELB-HealthChecker|"") { return 403; }
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me in 1.2.3:

```
    if ($http_user_agent !~* "(ELB-HealthChecker|^$)") { return 403; }
```